# Problems with move constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, move-semantics

I was testing a move constructor and did the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class X{
    public:
        int* p;
        int size;
        X(){}
        X(int n) : size(n){
            p = new int[n];
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                p[i] = i;
            cout << "Constructor\n";
        }
        ~X(){
            delete[] p;
        }
        X(const X& r){
            cout << "Copy\n";

        }
        X(X&& r){
            p = r.p;
            size = r.size;
            r.p = NULL;
            r.size = 0;
            cout << "Move\n";
        }
};
int main() {
    X a(10); //constructor    
    X b(a); // copy
    X c(X(3)); //constructor, move
    return 0;
}
```

What I expected in the output is in the comments, but when compiling (VS 2012) move constructor is not called?! But, if I add additional parameter to constructor:

```
string name;
X(int n, string _name) : size(n), name(_name){
    p = new int[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        p[i] = i;
    cout << "Constructor\n";
}
```

and then

```
X a(10, "a"); //constructor
X b(a); // copy
X c(X(3, "pom")); //constructor, move
```

i get results as expected... I really don't understand why.

**EDIT:** Now tested on GCC 4.7.2 and it does not call Move constructor in both cases but C++ Builder XE5 compiler calls Move constructor in both cases. Yet, VS calls it only in the second case (when using additional constructor parameter). Very interesting...

Comment: Try using [`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move).

Comment: I know about std::move but that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Of course it doesn't, otherwise I would have written an answer instead of a comment. :)

Comment: It could be that the compiler is optimizing `X c(X(3))` to turn it into `X c(3)`. The compiler is allowed to do that. It's essentially a return-value optimization: Even before move semantics, if a function returns something by value to a caller who assigns to it, I believe the compiler is allowed to only allocate the variable once in its final location on the stack and "pretend" to return it.

Comment: Ben's hypothesis is solid. Best set a breakpoint at X c(X(3)) and have a look at the disassembly and/or try without any optimizations.

Comment: See [minimal example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1e9a9bedf39c1ed) compiled with disabled optimization (-O0).

Comment: "When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit the copy/move construction of a class
object, even if the copy/move constructor and/or destructor for the object have side effects." [Such as debug output ;-)] (12.8/31 Copying and moving class objects)

Comment: And further below the case at hand: "when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference (12.2) would be copied/moved
to a class object with the same cv-unqualified type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by
constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the omitted copy/move"

Comment: Yes. It seams Ben is correct. X c(X(3)) is turned into X c(3) in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler is eliding the move construction and directly constructing `X(3)` into `c`, essentially turning your initialization into

```
X c(3);
```

With gcc, you can disable this using the `-fno-elide-constructors` switch. Once you add that, the output from your original example is as expected:

```
Constructor
Copy
Constructor
Move
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4c671af00e1c6ff)